# Collecting Java Heap Dump via apport

Tags: java, crash, apport

We have a Java application server which does real-time audio/video processing and for that purpose, it consumes a lot of memory (25+GB of RAM). Due to some, yet unknown, mistake in our JNI, every now and then our JVM crashes.

Our server runs on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` and when our JVM crashes, it behaves very strangely. It begins dumping the heap dump into `/var/crash`, it reaches the size of ~1.4GB (compressed) and halts, overwriting the heap dump with 50KB of data.

Apport log:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 30913) Tue Oct 23 12:38:49 2018: called for pid 29206, signal 6, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 30913) Tue Oct 23 12:38:49 2018: executable: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java (command line "<JAVA COMMAND AND OPTIONS GO HERE>")
ERROR: apport (pid 30913) Tue Oct 23 12:38:49 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 30913) Tue Oct 23 12:59:30 2018: core dump exceeded 11238 MiB, dropped from /var/crash/_usr_lib_jvm_java-8-oracle_bin_java.0.crash to avoid memory overflow
ERROR: apport (pid 30913) Tue Oct 23 12:59:30 2018: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_jvm_java-8-oracle_bin_java.0.crash
```

It seems that `apport` is rather unpredictable. In addition to this, contrary to what `apport` says, it does not utilize the `kernel.core_uses_pid` - every single heap dump uses the name `_usr_lib_jvm_java-8-oracle_bin_java.0.crash`.

1. Is there some alternative to `apport` for capturing java heap dump?
2. If not, is there a way to capture the whole heap dump?
3. Finally, how about `core_uses_pid`? `Apport`'s source suggests it should be used, but the filenames says different.

If I can update the question with any additional info please do not hesitate to ask. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you have a memory leak: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyvk or https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/